# how to read http headers in esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How do I set a property to the value of an incoming http request header?  I tried a few things (see following), but my log values are all null, so I'm clearly not reading the header values correctly.  The header value I really care about is X-EMPID.  Using wso2esb 4.8.1.

Here are a [couple](http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/08/route-messages-based-on-http-headers.html) of [posts](http://warunapw.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-read-http-headers-through.html) that led me to believe this would work, but I'm not having any luck yet.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="getaccount2"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="empid"
                   expression="get-property('transport', 'X-EMPID')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="emp_id" expression="get-property('empid')"/>
         </log>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="content_length"
                      expression="get-property('transport', 'Content-Length')"/>
         </log>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" expression="get-property('TRANSPORT_HEADERS')"/>
         </log>
```

Comment: BTW, I am setting the X-EMPID value in Apache, and sending to the ESB via a reverse proxy (using RequestHeader).  I know the header is being sent - I did a packet capture and checked it out with wireshark to be sure.

Comment: get-property('transport', 'X-EMPID') is the good way to get a HTTP Header named 'X-EMPID' : if your property is null, this header was not found in the request received by WSO2 ESB. in ESB_HOME/bin, you will find tcpmon, use it in front of WSO2 to verify the content of the request

Comment: Thank you very much.  I did not know about that tool - very helpful.  That helped me get to the bottom of it.  I wasn't proxying to the actual service endpoint, I was proxying to the administrative interface, which worked, but I'm guessing that it stripped any headers I had added.  I have things working as expected now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can conveniently access HTTP headers, which technically are transport headers in WSO2 ESB, by using XPath variables. The easiest way to read an HTTP header named `X-EMPID` is by using the following XPath: `$trp:X-EMPID`, where the `$trp` prefix indicates that the part following the colon is the name of a transport property. To log the header value you could use the following log mediator:

```
<log level="custom">
    <property name="X-EMPID value" expression="$trp:X-EMPID" />
</log>
```

To set the property `myProperty` to the value of `X-EMPID` HTTP header (which is already stored in a transport property) you would use the property mediator:

```
<property name="myProperty" expression="$trp:X-EMPID" />
```

The functionality is documented on [the WSO2 site](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse+XPath+Variables).

Comment: Thank you Kallja.  As you've probably surmised, I'm new to this.  I've spent a fair amount of time with the data services server, but this is my first time trying to use the esb.  Lots to learn.  Great product(s)!

Comment: @RonPeterson No problem. If my answer helped you do what you wanted please mark the answer as accepted to help others see that it's the way to go.

Comment: This is [what I've been working on](http://ronsrabbits.blogspot.com/2014/09/using-shibboleth-attributes-from.html).  Using Shibboleth to protect a web service.  Still requires interactive access to get past the IdP, but useful from Javascript, say.  Just got all of the pieces put together and working.