# How to get http head in log in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, monitoring, wso2-esb

I have many resources in an API in WSO2 ESB. I have to monitoring that API resources. For that, I want to log http head from requests.

According to [how to read http headers in esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854766/how-to-read-http-headers-in-esb) I have to do this:

```
<log level="custom">
    <property name="HTTP HEAD" expression="$trp:X-EMPID" />
</log>
```

But, I get null in System Log in WSO2 ESB.

How can I log this information?

EDIT: I get in System Log the next message

```
TID[-1234] [ESB] [2015-05-11 09:35:43,723] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - HTTP HEAD = null
```

Comment: Can you please attach sample logs you have generated with above setting?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm going to edit the article to add that information.

Comment: if you have a http header as X-EMPID , then above configuration should work . if X-EMPID is not in the http header only you will get null.