# WSO2 ESB print all TRANSPORT_HEADERS

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-esb

I can print individual transport headers in the WSO2 ESB with the following code inside a sequence:

```
<log level="custom">
    <property name="oneHeader" expression="$trp:FILE_NAME"/>
</log>
```

But I need to print all available transport properties. There is a axis2 property called "[TRANSPORT_HEADERS][1]", but when printing this property it is always empty.

```
<log level="custom">
    <property name="allHeaders" expression="get-property('axis2','TRANSPORT_HEADERS')"/>
</log>
```

Because I don't know all header names, I need to know **how to print all transport headers?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to print all the transport properties, but if you set a breakpoint in your sequence and enable debugging as described in https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Debugging+Mediation, you can find all the transport properties in the 'Variables' tab.[image: Variables tab]

Answer (score 0):

We can't log this property using property mediator since this is an internal JAVA Map in axis2-transports. Hence We may need to use a class mediator for this purpose.

Following is a sample one.

You may place the [class mediator jar](https://github.com/Nirothipan/log-transport-headers/raw/master/target/org.sample.logTransportHeaders-1.0.0.jar) directly in EI_HOME/lib or ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib and use the following config

```
<class name="org.sample.LogTransportHeaders"/>
```

in the proxy or API after adding following to log4j.properties file

```
log4j.logger.org.sample.LogTransportHeaders=INFO
```

Please refer here for further details : https://medium.com/@nirothipanram/wso2-ei-print-all-transport-headers-12aabb4027cc

Answer (score -3):

You can conveniently access HTTP headers, which technically are transport headers in WSO2 ESB, by using XPath variables. The easiest way to read an HTTP header named X-EMPID is by using the following XPath: $trp:X-EMPID, where the $trp prefix indicates that the part following the colon is the name of a transport property. To log the header value you could use the following log mediator:

```
<log level="custom">
  <property name="X-EMPID value" expression="$trp:X-EMPID" />
</log>
```

To set the property myProperty to the value of X-EMPID HTTP header (which is already stored in a transport property) you would use the property mediator:

```
<property name="myProperty" expression="$trp:X-EMPID" />
```

The functionality is documented on the [WSO2 site](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$trp).

[for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854766/how-to-read-http-headers-in-esb).

Comment: But the question is "Because I don't know all header names, I need to know how to print all transport headers?"

Comment: This answer does not help and does not answer the question asked by @FiveO