# WSO2 ESB get all transport headers

Tags: http-headers, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to get all transport headers in a sequence. I can get specific headers that I know the their names, but I want to get all of them including the ones that I do not know header names.

I find this question same, but there is no solution for our problem. 
[WSO2 ESB print all TRANSPORT_HEADERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132595/wso2-esb-print-all-transport-headers)

I tried also logging this

```
<property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" action="set" scope="axis2"/>
```

but I got nothing in WSO2 logs.

WSO2 version 6.4.0

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't log this property using property mediator since this is an internal JAVA Map in axis2-transports. Hence We may need to use a class mediator for this purpose.

Following is a sample one.

You may place the [class mediator jar](https://github.com/Nirothipan/log-transport-headers/raw/master/target/org.sample.logTransportHeaders-1.0.0.jar) directly in EI_HOME/lib or ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib and use the following config

```
<class name="org.sample.LogTransportHeaders"/>
```

in the proxy or API after adding following to log4j.properties file

```
log4j.logger.org.sample.LogTransportHeaders=INFO
```

Please refer here for further details : https://medium.com/@nirothipanram/wso2-ei-print-all-transport-headers-12aabb4027cc

Answer (score 1):

I have enabled wire logs in log4j.properties and restarted the server and It works fine for me.
I am using esb 4.9 version.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

[image: Transport Headers]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use the 'Transport headers' property exactly, but based on your problem description I think you can also solve your problem as follows:
You can log all headers by setting the log level in the carbon console
configure->logging->org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers to 'DEBUG'.

[image: example]