# WSO2 EI, getting HTTP request's message contents inside Sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have been reading [this documentation more than two weeks](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600) and it is still hard to understand some concepts.

Lets consider simple case. **User makes request to our API then EI must call specific endpoint depending on requests body and show response**.

Now there is the main problem on getting data of HTTP request.

I know that it could be accessed via `Property Mediator`, but [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Property+Mediator#PropertyMediator-Examples) does not help to understand anything.

1. if user makes `GET` request like this:

   ```
   https://my-ei-domain.com:8280/myapi/mymethod?query1=1&query2=2
   ```

   How it is possible to get values of `query1` and `query2`
2. If user makes `POST` request with `urlencoded` form data how to get them?
3. If user makes `POST` request with `JSON` body like this:

   ```
   {
      "var1": "one",
      "var2": 2,
      "var3": {
            "var3_var1": "two"
       }
   }
   ```

   How to get values of these variables?
4. User makes `POST` request with `XML` body:

   ```
   <body>
        <var1>1</var1>
        <var2>2</var2>
        <var3>
            <var1>3</var1>
        </var3>
   <body>
   ```

   How to get these values?
5. Next problem. Sometimes users will send some variables inside Headers of requests. How to get them?

These cases are not described well in documentation. Even if they are, they just scattered across multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **if user makes GET request like this...** . Using as described in
   documentation URL Template or URI mapping
   https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Working+with+APIs
2. **If user makes POST request with urlencoded form data how to get them...** There is no another way to get data as described above. Actually Content-Type is used to identify how data transfered and I think (since ESB server use apache http core lib, widely used) will able to handle param values. Anyway that is easy to reproduce. Create rest service, send urlencode request and see how it works.
3. **If user makes POST request with JSON body like this...** Rules are described in documentation how to work with json in synapse engine https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/JSON+Support (paragraph **Accessing content from JSON payloads**)
4. **User makes POST request with XML body:** to rest service ? to webservice?  Anyway, xpath is commonly used to access certain parts of xml documents. But, synapse engine has to identify that xml document is received and parse it. Engine relies on Content-Type, details in here https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters
5. **Next problem. Sometimes users will send some variables inside Headers of requests. How to get them?** In here [how to read http headers in esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854766/how-to-read-http-headers-in-esb)

Most of answers in documentation or easy to find by in web.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite long and I can see you are requesting tutorials on how to achieve these. I hope the following Wso2 related tutorials will help you:

[Enterprise Service Integration](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/11/enterprise-service-integration-wso2-esb/)

[Service Orchestration](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/service-orchestration-with-wso2-esb/)

[Restful Integration](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/12/restful-integration-with-wso2-esb/)

As an example let me explain the answers to a few of your questions:

To get information from a query like the following:

http://127.0.0.1:8280/pizzashop/api/menu/pizza?val=thin&type=crust

you may use property mediators like this:

```
<property name="Type" expression="$ctx:query.param.type"></property>
<property name="Val" expression="$ctx:query.param.val"></property>
```

WSO2 uses mediators to achieve most of the tasks. For example the [payloadFactory mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/PayloadFactory+Mediator) can be used to process the json and xml body and transform them. To process the following json

```
 { "payment":
        {
            "amount_lkr": "175.00",
            "card_no": "1234-5678-9876-5432"
        }
    }
```

we can use payloadFactory mediator as follows:

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="json">
             <format>{"purchaseInformation": {"amount": "$1","cc": "$2"}}</format>
             <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.payment.amount_lkr"></arg>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.payment.card_no"></arg>
             </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

Similarly this mediator and others can be used to process xml as well in a `POST` request.

Please learn from the tutorials. The details are too broad to be explained in a single answer