# WSO2 read property from the incoming request header

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to understand how I can read a property from the incoming request header.
What type of mediators do I have to access incoming request Headers?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the documentation: [Synapse XPath Variable `$trp`](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$trp)

```
<property name="stockprop" expression="$trp:Content-Type"/>
```

See also: [how to read HTTP headers in ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25854766)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to read incoming request headers is to use a property mediator and with the scope set to transport.

For example for a request header called TestHeader:

```
<property name=”TestHeaderValue” expression=”get-property(‘transport’,’TestHeader’)”/>
or
<property name=”TestHeaderValue” expression=”$trp:TestHeader”/>
```